# Use dynamic sorting is spring data jdbc custom query

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, spring-jdbc

I have the following `jdbc` repository method

```
@Query("select c.id, (select count(s.id) from student s where s.class_id=c.id) from class c limit :limit offset :offset")
List<ClassInfo> findClassInfo(Integer limit, Integer offset, Sort sort);
```

I need to include `sort` parameter into this native query. is it possible to do so?

Comment: Is this related to `spring-data-jdbc`?

Comment: @Rana_S yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevent you from doing this. But as of spring boot 3.0.3, this doesn't trigger the expected behavior